# Elasticsearch with python how to find a substring in string like SQL request?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Using python with Elaticsearch I use this json request...

```
mySearch2 = {"_source": {"includes": ["assigned_to", "start_date"]},
                "query":{"bool":
                    {"should":
                                [{"match": {"assigned_to":"RED"}}]
                    }
                }
                }
```

And documents I got are with "`RED WHITE BLUE`" or "`WHITE BLUE RED`" and got no "`WHITE RED BLUE`".

It seems answer is just the beginning or the end of the field, and I would like also to grab document with this substring in in the middle of the string.

Please could you help?

**Edit, mapping:**

```
"assigned_to": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: "assigned_to": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }

Comment: Your query should work .Is it your full query? Some other part might be excluding  that document

Comment: The whole query is here, in mySearch2. It is why I ask for some help. It drives me crazy, there is not a lot of help and samples to explain the things. I do not understand the un-consistency between few samples, Lucene in Grafana and the dictionnaries in python passed to the Elasticsearch import. It is not understandable. Big lack of clear documentation and a lot of samples with their explanations.

Comment: Can you add full response?. Default size is 10 docs can that be the issue?

Comment: Man, it's already the case, I've size 1000.